# Double click and Drag&Drop on ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have small web app. It receives two parameters from URL. There parameters represents folders which are created (if not yet exists) in share location defined in Web.config, like folder and subfolder i.e. \share\param1\param2.
On web I have ListBox where are shown files, which user can upload to path specified above. If path already exists, and there are some files present, they are show in that ListBox when page is loaded.
There is also button for open or download files (depend on file type), and button for delete file.

How can I make this two updates:

1. Open or download file on double click on item in ListBox
2. Now I am choosing files via Choose files button, how to make it via Drag&Drop?

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DmsNorway.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Document Management System</title>
    <style>
        body {font-family: sans-serif}
        h2 {text-align: center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h2>Document Management System</h2>
        <div>
            <h3>Files</h3>            
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbFiles" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="614px"></asp:ListBox>                         
        </div>
        <div>            
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fu1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" style="margin-left:395px"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btFiles" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btFiles_Click" style="margin:5px" OnClientClick="target ='_self';" />
                <asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btDelete_Click" style="margin:5px" OnClientClick="target ='_self';" />
                <asp:Button ID="btOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" OnClick="btOpen_Click" style="margin:5px" OnClientClick="target ='_blank';" />
            </p>
        </div>
                   
        <div>            
            <asp:Label ID="laTmp2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web cofig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="shareDir" value="\\CZPCU025\DMS_Norway"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DmsNorway
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string share = ParsePath(Request.QueryString["folder1"], Request.QueryString["folder2"]);
            if (Directory.Exists(share))
            {                
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(share);
                FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.*");
                foreach(FileInfo fi in files)
                {
                    if (lbFiles.Items.FindByValue(fi.Name) == null)
                    {
                        lbFiles.Items.Add(fi.Name);                                                
                    }                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(share);
            }
        }

        private string ParsePath(string dir1, string dir2)
        {
            dir1 = dir1.Replace('^', ' ');
            dir1 = dir1.Trim();
            dir1 = dir1.Replace('\\', '_');
            dir1 = dir1.Replace('/', '_');
            dir2 = dir2.Replace('\\', '_');
            dir2 = dir2.Replace('/', '_');
            string sharePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareDir"];
            string sh = Path.Combine(sharePath, dir1);
            string share = Path.Combine(sh, dir2);
            return share;
        }

        protected void btFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(fu1.PostedFile != null && fu1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string share = ParsePath(Request.QueryString["folder1"], Request.QueryString["folder2"]);                                                
                if (!Directory.Exists(share))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(share);
                }

                foreach (var uploadedFile in fu1.PostedFiles)
                {
                    string justFile = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);

                    //string saveLoc = Server.MapPath("upload") + "\\" + justFile;
                    string saveLoc = Path.Combine(share, justFile);
                    try
                    {
                        uploadedFile.SaveAs(saveLoc);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        laTmp2.Text = ex.Message;
                    }

                    lbFiles.Items.Add(justFile);

                }
            }
        }

        protected void btDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbFiles.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string share = ParsePath(Request.QueryString["folder1"], Request.QueryString["folder2"]);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(share, lbFiles.SelectedItem.Text);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    fi.Delete();
                    lbFiles.Items.Remove(lbFiles.SelectedItem);
                }

            }     
        }

        protected void btOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbFiles.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string share = ParsePath(Request.QueryString["folder1"], Request.QueryString["folder2"]);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(share, lbFiles.SelectedItem.Text);
                string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                string justFile = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    switch (fileExt.ToLower())
                    {
                        case ".xlsx":
                        case ".xls":
                            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + justFile);
                            break;
                        case ".txt":
                            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                            break;
                        case ".pdf":
                            Response.ContentType ="Application/pdf";
                            break;
                        case ".jpeg":
                        case ".jpg":
                            Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
                            break;
                        case ".png":
                            Response.ContentType = "image/PNG";
                            break;
                        case ".gif":
                            Response.ContentType = "image/GIF";
                            break;
                        default:
                            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + justFile);
                            break;
                    }
                    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                    Response.End();
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                string jScript = "<script>window.close();</script>";
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "keyClientBlock", jScript);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you setup a "nice" up-loader utility. there are "oh so many". And many support drag + drop. In other words, using the simple file upload control is un-friendly, does not show progress. A good file up-loader also "chunks" the file uploading process, so file size is not limited, but I think the progress bar, cancel upload, multiple files, and the drag + drop ability to up-load quite much suggests these days that a up-loader utility is a whole lot less work then "rolling" your own such system.

Then, in place of a listbox, create a gridview (or listview). That way you can list out the files, and place/have a download and delete button on that grid.

The result is a far better UI, one that will take no more code then your have, but the results are oh so much better.

In fact, I even suggest using a tab control, or even say a radio button, and you hide/show the file list, and the up-loader.

So, say this markup:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Height="40px"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rMyChoice" ClientIDMode="Static"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Upload Files</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>My Files</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />

        <div id="uploadfiles" runat="server" style="width: 30%">
            <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
                OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"
                OnClientUploadCompleteAll="AllDone" />
        </div>

        <div id="myfiles" runat="server" style="width: 30%">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridFiles_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileDate" HeaderText="UpLoaded" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileSize" HeaderText="Size" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDownLoad"
                                runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                                OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click"> 
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete"
                                runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                                OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"> 
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
        </div>
```

So, in my case, I used the free ajaxtoolkit uploader. But as noted, you can use one of many such controls - and many are free.

So, code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            LoadGridFiles();
            ShowArea();
        }
    }

    void LoadGridFiles()
    {
        DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
        MyTable.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("FileDate", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("FileSize", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("FullFile", typeof(string));

        var strFolder = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles");

        DirectoryInfo MyDir = new DirectoryInfo(strFolder);
        FileInfo[] MyFiles = MyDir.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo MyFile in MyFiles)
        {
            MyTable.Rows.Add(MyFile.Name,
                MyFile.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString(),
                MyFile.Length.ToString(),
                MyFile.FullName);
        }

        GridFiles.DataSource= MyTable;  
        GridFiles.DataBind();   
    }
```

So, above takes the folder, and creates a table, and then send to gv.

The uploader code for the ajax file upload:

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        // save file to up-loads folder
        string strSaveFile = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/" + e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(strSaveFile);
    }
```

And then our delete and download button:

```
    protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton myBut = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)myBut.NamingContainer;
        string strFile = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string strFullFile = Server.MapPath($"~/UpLoadFiles/{strFile}");
        File.Delete(strFullFile);   
        LoadGridFiles();


    }

    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton myBut = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)myBut.NamingContainer;

        string strFile = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string strFullFile = Server.MapPath($"~/UpLoadFiles/{strFile}");

        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFile);
        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
        Response.TransmitFile(strFullFile);
        Response.End();

    }
```

so, the result is now this:

[image]

So, it not a lot of code, or markup.

However, the result is a far better user experience.